# Is the following inequality involving matrix exponential true?

Tags: matrices, inequality, matrix-equations

Let $X$ and $L$ be real positive definite matrices.

$$\operatorname{Trace}(X^{-1}(X - e^{\log(X) - L})^2) \leq \operatorname{Trace}(XL^2)$$

where the exponential and the log are matrix exponential and log (defined as applying those functions to the eigenvalues)

I think I have for sanity check checked basic cases like when these are 1x1 or which basically implies the inequality for the case when X and L are diagonal which in turn implies it for the case when X and L commute.

I would love to have a simple proof if it is true. Even if this is true under some mild conditions on L (like spectral norm $\le$ constant) that is fine too.

Thanks

Comment: It's false for $X=I_n,L=aI_n$ where $a<0$.

Comment: I am not sure about your example per say but there might be a slight error in an argument I had. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I think the statement might hold for PSD matrices L. I have modified the statement accordingly.

Comment: You don't need eigenvalues to define exponential and logarithm of a matrix; you can use power series: $$\exp X = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{X^n}{n!}.$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy in what applications is the power series of a matrix more important to use instead of the eigenvalues of a matrix? aren't eigenvalues more analytically important than power series?

Comment: @develarist : Not all linear matrices have enough eigenvectors for that definition to work, but the matrix exponential is still defined for those.